# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Worte" und "Wörter"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   ["Die Worte" vs. "die Wörter"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/die-worte-vs-die-w%C3%B6rter)

Wann sagt man „Worte“, wann „Wörter“?

Beide sind ein Plural vom Singular „Wort“ und ich nehme an, dass es **im Singular** wirklich ein und dasselbe Wort ist, nicht zwei gleiche Namen für unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Haben die beiden **im Plural** unterschiedliche Bedeutungen?

Gibt es einen regionalen Unterschied – ist das eine oder andere Wort in bestimmten Gebieten oder Ländern bevorzugt? Ich wohne derzeit in Österreich, welches Wort sollte ich nutzen?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*Wörter* ist tatsächlich nur der Plural von Wort. Du schreibst also zum Beispiel einzelne (!) Wörter oder hebst sie kursiv hervor. Wörter werden gewöhnlich durch Zwischenräume (Leerzeichen, Satzzeichen usw.) begrenzt.

*Worte* hingegen sagt oder schreibt jemand - *merk dir meine Worte*. Dabei bezieht man sich nicht auf die einzelnen Wörter, sondern auf einen Satz, eine Wendung oder auch eine ganze Rede.

Der [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,307445,00.html) gibt hier auch eine schöne Übersicht.

---

Daraus zitiere ich noch einmal, sehr interessant:

> Die Mehrzahl von Sprichwort lautet unlogischerweise Sprichwörter, eigentlich müssten es Sprichworte sein.

Und als Zusammenfassung:

> Um es auf eine Formel zu bringen: Wörter bestehen aus Buchstaben, Worte bestehen aus Gedanken.

Comment: Die "Formel" am Ende ist genial weil einfach zu merken. Danke!

Comment: Die Formel am Ende ist Quark. Auch Worte bestehen natürlich aus Buchstaben und nicht aus Gedanken. Das sage ich als Mann der nicht viele Worte macht.

Comment: @userunknown Als Mann, der ziemlich viele sinnlose Worte macht, wenn er etwas nicht richtig verstanden hat. Und das auch bei jahrealten Antworten. Um in deiner Logik zu antworten: Selbstverständlich ist die Formel kein Quark. Quark ist nämlich ein Milchspeiseprodukt und somit nicht in einer Formel, die wiederum aus Wörtern besteht, zu finden. Das wäre viel zu schmierig. Klar soweit?
Ach so. Du meintest gar keinen richtigen Quark. Warte mal. Ob das mit den Gedanken dann vielleicht auch...

Comment: @OregonGhost: Du willst nicht sagen "Gedanken" sei eine Metapher? Wofür, bitte? Oder um es anders auszudrücken: Unfug besteht nicht aus Quark, Unfug ist Quark.

Comment: @userunknown: Nein, das habe ich auch nicht geschrieben. Ich habe es nicht einmal angedeutet.

Comment: @OregonGhost: "Worte bestehen aus Gedanken" steht da. "Worte stehen für Gedanken" könnte man sagen, aber dann passt es nicht in diese Spruchform.

Comment: Der Zwiebelfisch ist Quark.

Answer (score 6):

Als kleine Ergänzung noch eine etwas ältere Darstellung:

> **Worte. Wörter.** *Worte* sind die hörbaren Ausdrücke, wenn sie in einer Rede einen zusammenhängenden Sinn ausdrücken, *Wörter* sind sie auſser diesem Zusammenhange. In einem *Wörterbuche* werden die erklärten Ausdrücke auſser allem Zusammenhange in einer Rede bloſs nach alphabetischer Ordnung aufgeführt, und daher hat man es nie ein *Wortebuch* genannt. Man sagt hingegen: die *Textesworte*, und nicht: die *Texteswörter*, wenn man in einer Predigt den Text vorlieset, über den man predigen will.

aus: Johann August Eberhard’s *Synonymisches Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*, 8. Auflage, Berlin (1837).

Comment: ſſſſſſſſſſſſſſſ

Answer (score 5):

### Worte

wird verwendet, wenn die Worte gemeinsam einen Sinn ergeben, bzw. wenn sie in einem bedeutungstragenden Zusammenhang stehen:

> Ilse lauschte gespannt den **Worten** ihrer Mutter.
>   Weise sind die **Worte**, die der Dichter schrieb.
>   Lasst den **Worten** Taten folgen!
>   Einsteins letzte **Worte** sind nicht bekannt, weil die Frau, die sie gehört hat, kein Deutsch verstand.

---

### Wörter

Von Wörtern spricht man, wenn mehrere Wörter ohne sinntragenden Zusammenhang gemeint sind. Ein Buch, in dem die Schreibweise einzelner Wörter festgehalten ist, ist daher kein Wortebuch, sondern ein Wörterbuch; denn die Wörter, um die es geht, stehen allein aufgrund ihrer lexikalischen Abfolge dort, wo sie stehen, und nicht, weil sie gemeinsam mit den sie umgebenden Wörtern einen Gedanken transportieren.

> Schreibe alle **Wörter** auf, die nur aus Vokalen bestehen!
>   Sehr viele deutsche **Wörter** beginnen mit dem Buchstaben S.
>   Hanf, Senf, Genf und fünf sind, abgesehen von Ableitungen (Estragonsenf, hundertfünf, …), die vier einzigen deutschen **Wörter**, die auf nf enden.

---

### »Wort« als Singularetantum

Es gibt eine weitere Bedeutung von »Wort«, allerdings eine, für die man keinen Plural bilden kann. Damit ist nämlich nicht eine Folge von Buchstaben gemeint, die zwischen zwei Leerzeichen steht, sondern eine gesamthafte Aussage, die gerne auch so lang sein kann, dass sie ein dickes Buch füllt.

> Das **Wort** Gottes
>   Ihr **Wort** steht gegen sein **Wort**. Das wird ein Gericht klären müssen.
>   Ein Wurm wie du hat hier nichts zu sagen. Hier gilt nur das **Wort** des Königs.

Mit dem »Wort Gottes« ist die ganze Bibel gemeint, die ja aus vielen tausend *Wörtern* besteht. (Hier wird »Wörter« verwendet, weil dabei der Umstand, dass sie eine gemeinsame Bedeutung haben, keine Rolle spielt. In diesem Zusammenhang sind es nur Dinge, die man abzählen kann.)

Comment: Gilt das mit dem Wort Gottes nicht für die Thora und den Koran?

Comment: Die jüdische Tora (gerne auch mit h, also Thora) steht 1:1 in der christlichen Bibel. Es sind die ersten fünf Bücher des alten Testaments (also die fünf Bücher Mose). Wenn also die ganze Bibel das Wort Gottes sein soll, dann auch ein Teil davon. Der Koran gilt den Moslems auch als Wort Gottes. Gott hat sein Wort dem Erzengel Gabriel verkündet, dieser dem Propheten Mohammed, und der hat es dann aufgeschrieben. (wird fortgesetzt)

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Interessanterweise gilt den Moslems auch die Thora und somit die ersten fünf Bücher der Bibel als Wort Gottes. Auch das Evangelium des Prophet *Isa bin Maryam*, den die Christen *Jesus Christus* nennen, ist für Moslems ein Wort Gottes. Und die christliche Bibel enthält sogar noch ein weiteres islamisches Wort Gottes: Das Buch der Psalmen.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Worte sind genug gewechselt / 
>   laßt mich auch endlich Taten sehen! /
>   Indes ihr Komplimente drechselt, /
>   kann etwas Nützliches geschehen.<sup>Goethe</sup>

Worte = words in sensible use

Wörter = words abstractly or randomly

Answer (score 1):

The Brockhaus from 1894 mentions under the keyword "[Deutsche Sprache (Geschichte)](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=124453)":

> Auch Neutra sind im Singular in die starke Deklination übergetreten, z. B. «Auge» und «Ohr» (mittelhochdeutsch ôre). Die neutrale Pluralendung *-er* kam im Altdeutschen nur wenig Wörtern zu. Die Zahl dieser hat allmählich zugenommen, bis im Neuhochdeutschen *-er* die regelmäßige Endung der Neutra geworden ist («Worte» hält sich heute neben dem gebräuchlichern Plural «Wörter» nur durch die Macht der schriftlichen Überlieferung).

Summarized: The plural forms derived from different times before and after a grammar (flexion) simplification. The author expected *Worte* to vanish and claimed printed/written media to be the only foothold preventing this.

I conclude from this, that the difference in meaning (correctly explained in the other answers) established itself by convention.

Answer (score -2):

*Worte* are words used in a passage or speech. *Wörter* are words of a language considered as individual entities, as in a dictionary (which is called a *Wörterbuch* for that reason)