# "Die Worte" vs. "die Wörter"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Worte" und "Wörter"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-worte-und-w%C3%B6rter)

*Worte* and *Wörter* are both plurals of *Wort*.

Is there a difference in meaning between them?

Comment: If somebody has an opinion as to whether such questions are duplicates, please voice your opinion [on the corresponding Meta question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594). Voting to leave open for now.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you can count the words *and*  the number of words matters, „Wörter“ is the right choice. Otherwise choose „Worte“.

Examples:

- „Deine netten Worte haben mir geholfen.“ – „Your kind words helped me.“ (number of words doesn’t matter)
- „Der Aufsatz soll mindestens 500 Wörter umfassen.“ – „Write an essay with at least 500 words.“ (number of words is important)

Comment: Or even simpler: if "Wort" means the unit of language than its plural is "Wörter" else "Worte" (or even without plural, i.e. a promise: "Ich gebe dir mein Wort")

Comment: Lejonet8: This is the single *best* variation of the rule that I've heard so far - easy to remember and to apply. Kudos!

Comment: Wenn man nach einem Dialog feststellt: "Der Worte sind genug gewechselt" kann man diese auch zählen.

Comment: @userunknown Man kann auch die Anzahl der gespendeten Trostworte zählen, nur ist diese nicht von Bedeutung.

Comment: @lejonet: Aber die Anzahl der Wörter des Satzes ist von Bedeutung?

Answer (score 14):

The way I learned it was:

**Wörter** are just words that have nothing to do with each other.

**Worte** are words that are connected so that they transport a message.

It's pretty much the same as the other answers though.

Comment: “Word that have nothing to do with each other” isn’t always a good description for the use of _Wörter_: Take _Mehrere Wörter bilden einen Satz._ (_Several words form a sentence._) A sentence consists of course of elements that are linked to each other.

Comment: True, do you have a suggestion how to say it differently?

Answer (score 5):

"Wörter" is the plural for Wort only.
"Worte" can also mean *speech*, or *meaning*.

E.g.

> Er sprach Worte des Bedauerns
>
> He expressed his condolences.

You cannot use "Wörter" in this context.

Comment: Es ist mir nicht ganz klar, was du ausdrücken möchtest. Kann man in allen anderen Fällen "Worte" und "Wörter" nach eigenem Geschmack verwenden? Ist "Worte" kein regulärer Plural, sondern hat nur eine begrenzte wohl definierte Bedeutung?

Comment: @Em1 Nein, Wörter und Worte haben schon unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Der Zwiebelfisch hat es ganz gut formuliert, was auch sonst: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-worte-woerter-a-307445.html

Comment: Was ist der Plural von Ehrenwort, Ehrenworte oder Ehrenwörter?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Emanuel was trying to say. If you are looking at the plural of each individual word, use "Wörter" (like the Wörter in a dictionary). If you're describing more than one word as a group or phrase or sentence together, use "Worte" (like the Worte he used to express his opinion).

Answer (score 2):

I always think of *Wörter* as just being more than one word. Like talking about how many new words you have to learn. Whereas, I think of *Worte* as being more like a group of words together. Like if you give a few words at a funeral.