# Was bedeutet die erste Flexion im Wörterbuch?

Tags: dictionary

Mein Wörterbuch hat zwei Flexionen nach jedem Wort:

> **Wort** das, -(e)s, Wörter/-e

Die zweite ist für den Plural, aber die erste?

Comment: That's the genitive ending. As in latin, this gives you a better hint on the declination than the nominative alone.

Comment: I would expect these things to be explained somewhere on the first pages of your *Wörterbuch*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann yep, me too but is not
https://imgur.com/a/5j91w

Comment: Slightly related: [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen “Worte” und “Wörter”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-worte-und-w%C3%B6rter)

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28718/1696).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das steht ganz sicher im Wörterbuch. Jedes Wörterbuch hat am Beginn ein Kapitel, in dem genau solche Dinge erklärt werden.

Aber diese Darstellung von Substantiven ist ein Quasistandard und wird in eigentlich allen gängigen Wörterbüchern verwendet:

1. Zuerst steht im Fettdruck das Wort im Nominativ singular. Ausgenommen sind Pluraliatantum, also Wörter, die keinen Singular haben (z.B. *Leute, Ferien*), diese stehen im Nominativ plural.
2. Danach steht entweder ein bestimmter Artikel im Nominativ singular (also *der, die* oder *das*) oder einer der Buchstaben *m, f, n* (häufig kursiv gedruckt), mit denen das grammatische Geschlecht des Substantivs angegeben wird. In manchen Wörterbüchern werden die Geschlechter auch mit *m, w, s* gekennzeichnet. Es gilt:

   - der, m = maskulin (männlich)
   - die, f, w = feminin (weiblich)
   - das, n, s = neutral (sächlich)

   > **Wort** das, **Wort** *n*, **Wort** *s*

   Bei Pluraliatantum fehlt diese Angabe, oder es steht dort nur ein Stich (-). In manchen Wörterbüchern steht diese Angabe auch erst hinter den anderen hier erläuterten Einträgen.
3. Es folgt das Wort im Genitiv singular (Genitiv plural bei Pluraliatantum), wobei hier meist nicht das ganze Wort abgedruckt wird, sondern nur das Suffix, das an den Wortstamm anzufügen ist. Wenn der Genitiv sich nicht vom Nominativ unterscheidet (z.B. *Mutter*), wird nur ein Stich gedruckt. Wenn ein Wort zwei Genitivformen hat, werden beide angegeben, das ist im Fall des Wortes *»Wort«* der Fall:

   > des Worts, des Wortes
4. Abschließend folgt das Wort im Nominativ Plural. Diese Angabe fehlt bei Pluraliatantum, weil der Plural ohnehin schon in (1) steht. Sie fehlt aber auch bei Singulariatantum, das sind Wörter, die keine Mehrzahlform haben (*Regen, Hunger, Post*). Auch hier wird im Normalfall nur ein Suffix angegeben. Wenn sich der Wortstamm aber ändert (z.B. durch Umlautung), wird das Wort ausgeschrieben. Und auch hier werden alle Formen angegeben falls es mehrere gibt, und auch das ist beim Wort *»Wort«* der Fall:

   > die Wörter, die Worte

Der ganze Eintrag lautet also beispielsweise so:

> **Wort** das, -(e)s, Wörter/-e

und bedeutet:

> Nominativ singular: **Wort**
>   Geschlecht: **sächlich** (das Wort)
>   Genitiv singular: (des) **Wortes** oder (des) **Worts**
>   Nominativ plural: (die) **Wörter** oder (die) **Worte**

Comment: Super Antwort, vielen Dank!