# Substantiv und Adjektiv Deklination: Zweck und Kongruenz

Tags: declension

Ich möchte Deutsch lernen, aber ich habe keinen Lehrer und brauche Hilfe.

Ich habe eine Tafel mit Deklinationen gefunden, aber ich weiß nicht wie diese benutzt werden. Ich verstehe nicht, ob Substantiv und Adjektiv gleichartig dekliniert werden.

Zum Beispiel: warum *Der kleine Prinz*, und nicht *Der kleine Prinze*? Wie kann ich anfangen, Deklinationen zu lernen? Was ist der Prozess?

In meiner Muttersprache (Baskisch) haben wir Deklinationen, aber es weicht ab, wir haben kein Geschlecht.

Entschuldigung, aber meine Fragen sind ein bisschen allgemein. Ich bin ratlos.

---

<sub>Ich lerne Deutsch erst seit einigen Wochen. **Fühlen Sie sich frei, mich zu korrigieren**.</sub>

Comment: Off topic, aber: Baskisch, wie cool! Ansonsten: ich nehme an du kannst auch Spanisch. Da funktioniert das ja ähnlich, nur halt mit zwei Geschlechtern und ohne Fälle.

Comment: Ich finde Wiktionary hilfreich, um gebeugte Formen nachzuschlagen: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Prinz https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:klein

Comment: @phipsgabler Ja, ich kann auch Spanisch. Dass ist warum habe ich nicht verstanden, wie die Deklination im Deutschen funktioniert. Weil auf Spanisch: el coche blanco (das weisse Auto) -> lo**s** coche**s** blanco**s** (die weiss**en** Auto**s**).
--
Danke, @CarstenS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substantive (im folgenden: Nomen) und Adjektive flektieren auf Deutsch völlig verschieden.

Nomen haben praktisch keine Kasusendungen mehr. Nur im Genitiv Singular maskulin und neutral gibt es die Endung **‑s** und im Dativ Plural die Endung **‑n**. (Die schwache Deklination und das Dativ-*e* sollte man für den Anfang unbedingt ignorieren.)

Für ein Nomen wie *Frau* (feminin mit *n*-Plural) bedeutet das, dass es in allen Kasus die gleiche Form aufweist: **Frau** im Singular und **Frauen** im Plural.

Für ein Nomen wie *Doktor* (maskulin mit *n*-Plural) gibt es eine kasusspezifische Form: **Doktors** im Genitiv Singular, sonst einheitlich im Singular **Doktor** und im Plural **Doktoren**.

Und schließlich für ein Nomen wie *Kind* (neutral mit *r*-Plural) zwei kasusspezifische Formen: **Kindes, Kinds** im Genitiv Singular, **Kindern** im Dativ Plural und sonst einheitlich im Singular **Kind** und im Plural **Kinder**.

Plural wird dagegen fast immer markiert, durch Umlaut (*a, o, u, au* > *ä, ö, ü, äu*) oder eine Endung (*‑e, ‑n, ‑r, ‑s*) oder beides. Nur beim sogenannten *Nullplural ohne Umlaut* sind Singular und Plural identisch: *der/die Lehrer*, *das/die Mittel*, *der/die Knochen*.

Da die Nomen kaum Kasusformen haben, gibt es die Konvention, sie in Deklinationstabellen  in Verbindung mit dem bestimmten Artikel anzugeben, da dieser relativ gut nach Kasus unterscheidet: im Singular maskulin Nom. Akk. Dat. Gen. *d**er** Doktor, d**en** Doktor, d**em** Doktor, d**es** Doktor**s***; im Plural *di**e** Doktoren, di**e** Doktoren, d**en** Doktoren, d**er** Doktoren*.

Adjektive, die sich mit einem Nomen verbinden, müssen dagegen eine Endung tragen. Hier ist die Lage kompliziert, da es zwei verschiedene Endungsreihen gibt. Die eine Reihe sieht so ähnlich aus wie die des bestimmten Artikels: im Singular maskulin z.B. *frisch**er** Kuchen, frisch**en** Kuchen, frisch**em** Kuchen, frisch**en** Kuchen**s***.

Die andere kennt nur *‑e* und *‑en*: im Singular z.B. *der frisch**e** Kuchen, den frisch**en** Kuchen, dem  frisch**en** Kuchen, des frisch**en** Kuchens*.

Da es im Internet genug Deklinationstabellen gibt, habe ich nur über die Systematik der Flexion gesprochen. Mehr Beispiele kann man leicht nachschlagen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Deklination von Adjektiven hängt zwar vom Geschlecht des dazu gehörenden Substantivs ab, muss aber nicht identisch sein. [Diese Seite](https://easy-deutsch.de/adjektive/adjektivdeklination/) zeigt das ziemlich gut.

Bei Substantiven ist in einem Wörterbuch die passende Deklination angegeben. Manche Wörterbücher nummerieren die Deklinationen nach Geschlecht und drucken sie in einem Tabellenteil ab, andere schreiben nur den Genitiv und den Plural auf, mit dem man sie selbst nachschlagen kann, siehe [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43174/1696).